# What's the relationship between Gauss' law and Newton-Leibniz formula?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, physics

Actually it's a puzzle I got in my Physics class.

Someone says Gauss' law actually is a specific example of the famous Newton-Leibniz formula, but I couldn't catch it.

So far I haven't learned about multivariable calculus, so maybe I need a simpler explanation~

**Remark**: Gauss' law: 
[a link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question seems to refer to a connection between (part of) the fundamental theorem of calculus and Stokes' theorem in $n$-dimensional space.

If the real valued function $f(x)$ has an antiderivative $F$ on $[a,b]$, that is $f(x) = F'(x)$, then
$\int_a^b f(x) dx = F(b)-F(a).$
More suggestively,
\begin{equation*}
\int_a^b F'(x) d x = F(b) - F(a),\tag{1}
\end{equation*}
the integral of the derivative over the interval can be found knowing only the value of the function at the boundary of the interval.

Stokes' theorem is a *generalization*,
\begin{equation*}
\int_M d\omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega.\tag{2}
\end{equation*}
This theorem says that we can find the integral of the exterior derivative of the form $\omega$ over the $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ by integrating the form over the boundary $\partial M$ of the manifold.
If you don't know what a form is, never mind. It is our $F$.
And $d$ is our derivative.
And $M$ is our volume.
Equation (2) is totally analogous to (1), we are finding the sum of the derivative of some object over a volume knowing only the value of that object on the boundary.
An appropriate response to this result is amazement.

When we say that Stokes' theorem is a generalization of (1) we mean that for $n=1$ it is (1).
(1) is a special case.
Another special case of Stokes' theorem is the divergence theorem in three-dimensional space,
$$\oint_V  \nabla\cdot {\bf F}\, dV = \oint_{\partial V}  {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf S}.$$
If you continue on in physics you will learn very well this and other related results in multidimensional calculus in a good course on electromagnetism.
Rather than say more about the divergence theorem, we give below a summary of the important analogies between the various theorems.

$$\begin{array}{llcccccc}
&
\textrm{Theorem}
    & \textrm{Dimension}
    & \textrm{Object}
    & \textrm{Derivative}
        & \textrm{Volume}
            & \textrm{Surface}  \\ \hline
\textrm{Stokes'}
    & \int_M d\omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega
    & n
    & \omega
    & d\omega
        & M
            & \partial M \\
 \\
\textrm{Fund. Thrm.}
    & \int_a^b F'(x) d x = F(b) - F(a)
    & 1
    & F(x)
    & F'(x)
        & [a,b]
            & a,b \\
  \\
\textrm{Divergence}
    & \oint_V  \nabla\cdot {\bf F}\, dV = \oint_{\partial V}  {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf S}
    & 3
    & {\bf F}
    & \nabla\cdot {\bf F}
        & V
            & \partial V \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 3):

It's not a "specific example" but rather can be seen as an extension to higher dimensions. The Newton-Leibniz formula gives the integral of a function derivative in terms of the value of the function on the "surface" of a line (i.e the end points).

Similarly, the [Divergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) (as Gauss's Law is known in mathematics), expresses the integral over the divergence of the electric field which is the current density (loosely a 3D derivative) in terms of the value of the electric field on the surface of the volume.